# Enable recpatcha on all CiviCRM Contribution pages which does not include profiles

Tags: profile, contribution-page, recaptcha

I need to include recaptcha on all donation pages in CiviCRM.

CiviCRM: 4.7.13

Drupal: 7.5.0

I know we can enable the "Include recaptcha" in profile settings. But few donation pages does not have profiles configured and I am bit worried how to add recaptcha for those donation pages.

Any help would be greatly apppreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify your use case for a Contribution page that has no fields on it to collect info on who is making the donation

Answer (score 1):

You can add a profile that only captures email address.  Since that's already captured on a contribution page, it doesn't change what appears, but it lets you add a CAPTCHA.